# How to use and display custom font in XCode Version 14.2?

Tags: flutter, xcode, fonts

I did all the steps in order to add custom font in XCode and it appeared in the list of fonts
[image]

[image]

But when I run the app in the simulator I still see system font

[image]

Does anyone know what could go wrong?

Thank you!